# Regular expression detecting hard coded messages

Tags: c#, regex, localization, internationalization

I work on a solution potentially having hard coded strings. The task is to identify in the solution's (C# in my case) code, all the phrases that aren't touched by the translation mechanism.

Usually the translations mechanisms are something like

```
myTranslator.Get("messageKey", myLang)
```

so I supposed `"\w .*"` would potentially give me phrases (I use a space after a word, cause in the Message Keys you rarely have spaces...), but that gave me also the HTML attributes like `class="alpha beta gamma"` that are not phrases...

"fortunately", the supposed hard coded strings are in *French*, so I tried to find

```
".*[äÄëËüÜïÏöÖâÂêÊûÛîÎôÔèÈàÀùÚçÇéÉ].*"
```

in the `*.cs;*.cshtml` files (the solution is an ASP.NET one)...

That works rather well, but finds only phrases having accents... is there a smarter way to identify the hard-coded (non-translated) strings in solution's code?

What are the general recommendations to identify, label and remove such kind of strings from a (localisable) solution?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what input string you are passing in and what the expected match is.

Comment: I search in all solution's code strings that are not code, but hard-coded (untranslated) phrases, like "Fermer la fenêtre" ("Close the window")